# selenium object identification Issue while navigating from one page to another in same window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While navigating from one webpage to another web page in same window the selenium is showing that no such element is found on second page. For example it is able to find the objects till login page after successful login it is not recognizing the objects. Kindly tell me why this is happening and what is the solution of it. For the second Method i am facing the issue. I used thread. sleep and switch window still facing the problem.

```
public void LoginKaplan() {

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        kecUserNameTextBox.sendKeys("abc");
        kecPasswordTextBox.sendKeys("123#");
        userNameTextBox.sendKeys("a1");
        passwordTextBox.sendKeys("1234");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='productName_chosen']/a/span"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//div[@id='productName_chosen']/div/div/input"))
                .sendKeys("DAT2015");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);

        List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By
                .xpath("//*[@id='productName_chosen']/div/ul/li[2]/em"));
        WebElement element = wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
                        .xpath("//*[@id='productName_chosen']/div/ul/li[2]/em")));

        for (WebElement webElement : findElements) {
            if (webElement.getText().equals("DAT2015")) {
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                webElement.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='syllabusPath_chosen']/a/span"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//div[@id='syllabusPath_chosen']/div/div/input"))
                .click();

        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//div[@id='syllabusPath_chosen']/div/div/input"))
                .sendKeys("/DAT2015/assessments/secTests/qdatoatnatsciA15");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        List<WebElement> findElements2 = driver.findElements(By
                .xpath("//div[@id='syllabusPath_chosen']/div/ul/li/em"));
        WebElement element2 = wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
                        .xpath("//div[@id='syllabusPath_chosen']/div/ul/li/em")));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        for (WebElement webElement : findElements2) {
            if (webElement.getText().equals(
                    "/DAT2015/assessments/secTests/qdatoatnatsciA15")) {
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                webElement.click();
                break;
            }
        }

        loginButton.click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}

//Method 2----------------------------------------------------
    public void QuestionsAns() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(22000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver.findElement(
                By.id("subitem0.singleAnswerMultipleChoice.answerChoiceRow1.state0"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("img2.simNext")).click();
        driver.findElement(
                By.id("subitem0.singleAnswerMultipleChoice.answerChoiceRow2.state0"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("img2.simNext")).click();
        driver.findElement(
                By.id("subitem0.singleAnswerMultipleChoice.answerChoiceRow2.state0"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("img2.simNext")).click();

    }
```

Comment: are you doing login in iframe? If so, you need to switch back to default window after successful login using driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Comment: Because when page switches at that time page takes some time to load all element and selenium try to find but still element not always ready so you are getting this issue. After successful login please user thread.sleep(5000) means 5 seconds OR you can use wait method.

Comment: hi, I tried those above steps still facing the same issue. I have pasted my code can you please give me the solution of it. #thanks

Comment: Why you have put  driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); after login? also why you are using too much implicit wait?

Comment: There is lot of synchronization issue in that application thats why i am using a lot of wait. After commenting the driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); it is also not working.

Comment: If your browser tab before login and after login is same then you should not do anything other than wait. can I have URL where you are testing?

Comment: That application is in the UAT server. You can't access that out side network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do view Source and search for "iframe"tag . You will get the tag name using that you can also switch between frames. You can use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`
or

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0); //try with index 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the object to appear

```
WebDriverWait wait;
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by)));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by)));
```

These wait function will wait until the object is clickable or visable on the web page.